# Conic programming duality - relative interior

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, dual-cone

Consider the primal/dual conic programming problems
$$
\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\left< #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\bvec}[0]{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\cvec}[0]{\mathbf{c}}
\newcommand{\xvec}[0]{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\yvec}[0]{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\zvec}[0]{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{align}
    \textrm{(Primal)} \quad \max &\{ \ip{\cvec, \xvec}
        : \bvec - A\xvec \in L,
        \xvec \in K \} \tag{1} \label{eq:P}
    \\
    \textrm{(Dual)} \quad \min &\{ \ip{\bvec, \yvec}
        : A^T\yvec - \cvec \in K^*,
        \yvec \in L^* \} \tag{2} \label{eq:D}
\end{align}$$
where $K$ and $L$ are closed convex cones.  Such a formulation is given in e.g. section 4.7 of Gärtner and Matousek's "Approximation Algorithms and Semidefinite Programming".  They state that if the primal has finite value $\gamma$ and has an interior point then the dual is feasible and has the same value $\gamma$ (strong duality).

They define an interior point as a feasible point such that:

- (IP:1) in the case that $L$ is full dimensional, $\bvec-A\xvec \in \operatorname{int}(L)$
- (IP:2) if $L=\{0\}$ then $x \in \operatorname{int}(K)$.

Is there a more general statement that can be made in the case that $L$ is not full dimensional and not $\{0\}$?

For example, I would think that one could obtain strong duality by defining an interior point to be one in which $\bvec-A\xvec\in\operatorname{relint}(L)$ and $\xvec\in\operatorname{relint}(K)$, where $\operatorname{relint}$ is the relative interior.  My reasoning on this is as follows: one could define the slack variable $\zvec=\bvec-A\xvec$ in order to obtain the program
$$\begin{align}
\max \{ \ip{\cvec, \xvec} : \bvec - A\xvec - \zvec=0, \xvec \oplus \zvec \in K \oplus L \}.
\tag{3}\label{eq:Aeq}
\end{align}$$
Now characterization (IP:2) applies since $A$ only appears in the equality constraints.  Unfortunately, $\operatorname{int}(K \oplus L)$ will be empty if either cone is not of full dimension.  But $K$ and $L$ will be full dimension within their affine subspaces (which will  be some subspace of the vector space that $K \oplus L$ is in).  The components of $\xvec \oplus \zvec$ orthogonal to that space are forced zero and so these variables can be removed from the problem with no effect.  Consequently, strong duality for $\eqref{eq:Aeq}$ holds if there is an $\xvec \oplus \zvec \in \operatorname{relint}(K \oplus L) = \operatorname{relint}(K) \oplus \operatorname{relint}(L)$ with $\bvec - A\xvec - \zvec=0$.  Equivalently, strong duality holds for $\eqref{eq:P}$ if there is an $x \in \operatorname{relint}(K)$ such that $\bvec-A\xvec \in \operatorname{relint}(L)$.  And the dual of $\eqref{eq:Aeq}$ is equivalent to $\eqref{eq:D}$.

Is this reasoning sound?  If so, is there a citeable reference that spells this out?  And, is there some even more general statement?  My characterization is strictly more general than (IP:2) but does not include (IP:1), since that does not require $x\in\operatorname{relint}(K)$, only $x \in K$.